# Load image only when image tag container comes in viewport

Tags: jquery, viewport

In photo gallery all images are loaded in thickbox , I wants to load the original thumbnail of the slider when its container div comes into the viewport.My HTML structure is:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="content">
<div>
<a href="path1"><img src="default-loading.gif" data-original="img1"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div>
<a href="path1"><img src="default-loading.gif" data-original="img1"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div>
<a href="path2"><img src="default-loading.gif" data-original="img2"/></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div>
<a href="path3"><img src="default-loading.gif" data-original="img3"/></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Container has multiple content blocks and each block having an img tag. I am using jquery viewport.js to bind an event on each "content" div.

```
$(".content").each(function(){
if($(this).is(':in-viewport')){
//change src of image
}
});
```

But it identifies all content blocks in visible mode.

My requirement is to load only those images which are coming to the viewport only.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks
Gaurav

Comment: Try this plugin - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: [this jsFiddle looks good to me. just requirees a bit of tweaking](http://jsfiddle.net/KunRv/). Where are you caught at?

Comment: you mean lazy loading: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+lazy+loading&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

Mika's [Viewport Selectors](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) plugin works for the browser window viewport and not html elements. In other words if you got some css like `#container{width:350px;height:150px;overflow:auto;}` it will not work when scrolling.

I recommend trying his other plugin, [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/efazos/1/edit